# Increase Graphics Quality unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can i create best quality graphics in unity. When i put 3d models in game level there is white lines or dots on 3d models which looks very bad. I have attached the image of that 3d models. I also increased antialiasing and texture resolution from `Project setttings -> Quality` but there is no change in graphics quality.[image]

Comment: This is more of an artistic question than what really belongs on StackOverflow, but first off, enable anti-aliasing to get rid of the god-awful jaggies. Second, change your light color to something other than pure white. Third, learn about normal mapping. You'd be surprised how much of the perceived quality of a model/level is actually just the lighting/texturing.

Comment: Oh yeah and getting some shadows in there would help too.

Comment: I agree, and would like to add that this question would be best asked on answers.unity3d.com, as that site is just like stackoverflow but specialized on unity3d questions.

Comment: @Adam S. Yes you are right but on answers.unity3d.com people do not post answers as like on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those dots and the lines are considered Aliasing. You can rid them from the scene by going into Edit > Project Settings > Quality > Anti Aliasing

Anti-Aliasing does take a substantial performance hit as well.

Another really awesome thing that Unity3D has to help out with quality is it's usage of Beast Lightmapping. You can access the Lightmapping panel by clicking Window > Lightmapping.

I would read up on the Unity3D docs for more info on lightmapping:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Lightmapping.html

Happy Developing!